# Search addresses by Two ERC20 Tokens

Tags: tokens, erc-20, explorers, explorer-api

**Hello, friends!**

How to find Eth addresses that are stored at the same time 2 (or 3) defined ERC20 tokens?

I'm just an ordinary user, 
so would be grateful for the solutions to make it simple.

*Thanks!*

Comment: etherscan shows all the tokens of an account, just enter the address

Comment: Two coins at the same time to be on these addresses. The point is to find addresses, all of which have these two selected coins at the same time. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Etherscan shows all the tokens that belongs to an address, if I am not wrong this covers "two coins at the same time to be on this address"